# WPF - Setting window size to child usercontrol size

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a tab control that is dynamically populated with tabs that contain user controls of various sizes.  When a tab is opened I want the window to automatically resize to a size that makes sense given the active user control.  Is there a clean way to do this?

I'm using a standard mvvm pattern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the **SizeToContent** property on the **Window** class.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        SizeToContent='Width'>
  <Grid>
    <Button Width='200' Content='The Button' />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: works great, used the 'widthandheight' option for sizetocontent